# Linux how to determine cron config files location?

Tags: linux, cron

As I know that we can setting to grant access for users to cron facility also can revoke access for some users.

But I dont know where to put my setting for cron read those. I've tried with 
(/etc/cron.allow, /ect/cron.deny), (/var/spool/cron/cron.allow, /var/spool/cron/cron.deny) but It not work. The user added to cron.deny still can access to cron facility.

How can I determine where to put setting for cron on my system?

**Update as comment**

My case is I created two user: **user1**, **user2** and add **user1** to **cron.allow**, **user2** into **cron.deny**. Then I create a job for each using crontab with expect that **user1** can get cron run and **user2** will not. but the result is user2 also get cron job run.

Additional, I test this with busybox crond. By Looking at source code, It seem that busybox version not check cron.allow/cron.deny at all.

Can anyone confirm that?

Thanks

Comment: If possible could you please update your question with contents of /etc/cron.deny and /etc/cron.allow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I test this with busybox crond. By Looking at source code, It seem
>   that busybox version not check cron.allow/cron.deny at all.
>
> Can anyone confirm that?

I confirm. Neither [`crond.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/miscutils/crond.c) nor [`crontab.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/miscutils/crontab.c) contains "cron.allow" or "cron.deny". And this reflects the promises of [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html) (**emphasis** by me):

> BusyBox combines **tiny versions** of many common UNIX utilities into a
>   single small executable.
>
> … The utilities in BusyBox generally have **fewer options** than their
>   full-featured GNU cousins…
>
> BusyBox has been written with **size-optimization** and **limited resources**
>   in mind.